# java inverted pyramid of numbers?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I was asked to create a java program that will display an inverted pyramid of numbers (1 to 9 only). with user input of how many number of rows.

I don't know how to loop and limit the numbers to 9 and change it to the right side.

My code is:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter height:\t");
        int height = sc.nextInt();
        
        for (int row = height; row >= 1; row--) {
            for (int col = 1; col <= row; col++) {
                System.out.print("");
            }
            for (int k = 1; k <= row; k++) {
                System.out.print(row + "");
            
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

the output is:

```
Enter height:   12
121212121212121212121212
1111111111111111111111
10101010101010101010
999999999
88888888
7777777
666666
55555
4444
333
22
1
```

the output should be:

```
Enter height:  12
    111111111111
     22222222222
      3333333333
       444444444
        55555555
         6666666
          777777
           88888
            9999
             111
              22
               3
```

OR:

```
Enter height:  20
11111111111111111111
 2222222222222222222
  333333333333333333
   44444444444444444
    5555555555555555
     666666666666666
      77777777777777
       8888888888888
        999999999999
         11111111111
          2222222222
           333333333
            44444444
             5555555
              666666
               77777
                8888
                 999
                  11
                   2
```

Comment: Your sample outputs are right-triangles, not pyramids - is this intentional?  Did the assignment include these as examples or is there is a description of the of the output?

Comment: Your post contains (at least implicitly) three questions: 1. limit the pyramid to numbers between `1` and `9` - 2. make the pyramid ascending instead of descending - 3. make the pyramd right- insted of left-aligned. My comment will only tackle the 1st question since this is the one you explicitly asked about. --- I would suggest to use a separate variable to represent the digit used for the current line. We can write some custom logic to reset it to `1` when it is `>= 10`, e.g. by using an [`if` statement (`oracle.com`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main loop is running from height to 0 which is causing the numbers you print to be from height to 1 where as output expects it in ascending order.

output further expects that any value of height greater than 9 be treated as single digit increments again so after 9 comes 1 again instead of 10.

you have the write thought by appending space but to append space in java you actually have to add space in between the two ""

Example:

```
System.out.print(" ").
```

Fixing all above issues code snippet should look something like this :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter height:\t");
        int height = sc.nextInt();
        
        for (int row = 1; row <=height; row++) {
            for (int space = 1; space < row; space ++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int val = row ; val <= height; val++) {
                if(row>9){
                    System.out.print(row%10+1);
                }
                else{
                     System.out.print(row);
                }
            }
            System.out.println();           
        }
    }
```